# nHibernate concurrency version not being updated when editing child bag or child property

Tags: c#, nhibernate, concurrency, version

I am using nHibernate (3.3.3GA) concurrency with the version tag in my parent mapping file.

1, When I update my child collection (.add or .remove) the parent version doesn't update.

2, When I update a property on a child entity the parent version doesn't update.

The only time I can get the parent version to update is when I edit a property on the parent entity itself.

Could someone take a look and see if there is something I am missing or doing wrong?

I have the following code:

Parent Class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Parent
{
  public Parent()
  {
    this.Id = -1;
    this.Children = new List<Child>();
  }

  [DataMember(Name = "Id")]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  [DataMember(Name = "Name")]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [DataMember(Name = "Children")]
  public ILIst<Child> Children { get; set; }

  [DataMember(Name = "Deleted")]
  public bool Deleted { get; set; }

  [DataMember(Name = "Version")]
  public byte[] Version { get; set; }

  public override string ToString()
  {
    return this.Name;
  }
}
```

Child Class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Child
{
  public Child()
  {
    this.Id = -1;
  }

  [DataMember(Name = "Id")]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  [DataMember(Name = "Parent")]
  public Parent Parent { get; set; }

  [DataMember(Name = "Name")]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [DataMember(Name = "Deleted")]
  public bool Deleted { get; set; }

  public override string ToString()
  {
    return this.Name;
  }
}
```

Parent Mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="TestApp.Entities" auto-import="false">

  <class name="TestApp.Entities.Parent" table="TestDb.dbo.ParentTable" dynamic-update="true" lazy="false" optimistic-lock="dirty">

    <id name="Id" column="ParentID" type="int" unsaved-value="-1">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <version name="Version" generated="always" type="BinaryBlob" unsaved-value="null">
      <column name="Version" sql-type="timestamp" not-null="false" />
    </version>

    <property name="Name" column="Name" />

    <bag name="Children" table="TestDb.dbo.ChildTable" lazy="false" inverse="true" where="Deleted = 0" fetch="join">
      <key column="ParentID" />
      <one-to-many class="TestApp.Entities.Child" />
    </bag>    

  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Child Mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="TestApp.Entities" auto-import="false">

  <class name="TestApp.Entities.Child" table="TestDb.dbo.ChildTable" dynamic-update="true" lazy="false">

    <id name="Id" column="ChildID" type="int" unsaved-value="-1">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <many-to-one name="Parent" class="TestApp.Entities.Parent" column="ParentID" cascade="none" fetch="join" />

    <property name="Name" column="Name" />

  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

So next I edit the child collection within parent (.add or .remove) and hit save.  Parent version doesn't update.  Next I try editing child[0].Name and hit save, again parent version doesn't update.

I am using the following to save to the db:

```
public void Merge<T>(ref T entity) where T : class
{
  try
  {
    T updatedEntity = null;

    using (ISession session = this.SessionFactory.OpenSession())
    {
      using (session.BeginTransaction())
      {
        updatedEntity = (T)session.Merge(entity);

        session.Transaction.Commit();
      }
    }

    entity = updatedEntity;
  }
  catch (StaleObjectStateException sose)
  {
    throw sose;
  }
}
```

Can anyone spot the cause of why my parent version isn't updating when I edit my child collection?

many thanks

Comment: Well, your mapping says: `dynamic-update="true"` and you are not changing any value in the Parent table. So, there is no need to issue the UPDATE to the Parent table... which would cause the version increment. The point is: Version is incremented by DB engine. And only, if there is any change made to the row. no dependency to changes in the child/related tables

Comment: Ok, I have read several articles that claim to be doing what I am BUT they want to turn off updating the parent version when a child is edited.  I want the opposite, I need to have the parent version incremented when the child collection is edited.

Can anyone suggest a way to refactor my code to achieve this?

Comment: Well, in this case, the solution would be mostly in a business layer perspective change. For example, introduce some property/column like `LastUpdateDate` on the Parent (and set the new update date value in your *Merge* method) ... Seems weird? Well, if we want to change the version of the Parent, we have to change the Parent. Does it make sense?

Comment: Yeh that makes perfect sense.  It's just that I have read many people achieving what I am asking with just nhibernate settings, or so they claim, I have tried all their suggestions and mine will not work.  The only difference is that they were using older versions of nhibernate than I am.

Comment: Basically what should happen (from what I have read) is:
nHibernate would first create TSQL to `insert/update/delete` the child in question, then, execute an TSQL `UPDATE` statement to increment the parent version.  When I look at the generated TSQL that my app is producing, I am not getting the final `UPDATE` that increments the parent version.

Comment: I am trying to say: NHibernate cannot update the *Version* in the scenario above. Why? the mapping above clearly states: `generated="always"`. So we are instructing NHibernate: consume and check versions. But the **DB engine will increment** them. And while there is no UPDATE against the Parent... no version change. And I would say: in any version of NHibernate. Not only the latest. Does this make it clear? ;)

Comment: Ah ok, I am following now.  Yeh I've actually just been having a conversation with another developer in the office.  We've both looked at the mapping and said similar that the `version` property is a `timestamp` which is a DB controlled datatype.  Will try changing the `version` property to something like a `datetime` and play around with the `generated="always"` setting and see if this fixes the issue.

Comment: Please, check this: http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#example-parentchild-collections. a small citect *"...When we remove / add an object from / to a collection, the version number of the collection owner is incremented..."* So, for these actions (remove and add) the version managed by NH could be changed. If the child is changed updated... it won't

Answer (score 1):

Ok so with the help of **Radim Kohler** I have now fixed the problem.

Changing the 'version' column in the database from a `timestamp` to a `datetime` then altering the 'version' mapping as follows:

Before:

```
<version name="Version" generated="always" type="BinaryBlob" unsaved-value="null">
  <column name="Version" sql-type="timestamp" not-null="false" />
</version>
```

After:

```
<version name="LastUpdated" type="DateTime" unsaved-value="null">
  <column name="LastUpdated" sql-type="datetime" not-null="false" />
</version>
```

Has now solved the problem.  Now when I update my child collection with an `.Add()` or `.Remove()` or I edit a property of 1 or more children within the collection my parent 'LastUpdated' property is updated.